# Postman is not displaying the exception message while getting 500 response code

Tags: rest, postman, web-api-testing

Postman is not able to display the exception when getting response code 500 "internal server error". It is displaying the response correctly while getting 200 response code.
I am very new with Postman any idea why it is not displaying the error message? Is there any config that I need to do on postman side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no response body, which can be displayed by postman. Public facing APIs prolly shouldn't provide any more details.